# python: inputting a negative value into array keeps giving me 256 minus that value (image- prewitt edge detection)

Tags: python, edge-detection

I am trying to do simple prewitt edge detection on an image and output 2 images with horizontal and vertical edges. For some reason, whenever the output value should be negative (for example -3), my output array ends up with 256 minus that value (253) giving me a huge amount of background. I tried adding these if/elif/else statements but that helped not at all. I am using the code below and clueless as to what's going wrong:

```
for i in range(1,(len(os.listdir(images)))):
    image=plt.imread(images+(os.listdir(images)[i]))
    if len(image.shape)>2:
        img=image[:,:,0]
    else:
        img=image

    imgC=deepcopy(img)
    imgD=deepcopy(img)
    imgE=deepcopy(img) 

    for x in range(1,img.shape[1]-2):
        for y in range(1,img.shape[0]-2):
            avgA=(img[(y-1),x]+img[(y-1),(x+1)]+img[(y-1),(x-1)])
            avgC=(img[(y+1),x]+img[(y+1),(x+1)]+img[(y+1),(x-1)])
            avgT=(img[(y-1),(x-1)]+img[y,(x-1)]+img[(y+1),(x-1)])
            avgB=(img[(y-1),(x+1)]+img[y,(x+1)]+img[(y+1),(x+1)])

            if (avgA-avgC)<0:
                imgC[y,x]=0
            elif (avgA-avgC)>255:
                imgC[y,x]=255
            else:
                imgC[y,x]=(avgA-avgC)
            if (avgT-avgB)<0:
                imgD[y,x]=0
            elif (avgT-avgB)>255:
                imgD[y,x]=255
            else:
                imgD[y,x]=(avgT-avgB)
            imgE[y,x]=math.sqrt(((imgC[y,x]**2)+(imgD[y,x]**2)))
```

Comment: I don't know the solution to your problem but I think that if you do not divide your avgA, avgC, avgT, avgB by 3 (the number of elements you use to calculate the averages), you might end up with a lot more 255 than you  expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values in that image are stored as `unsigned byte`s (`0..255` range), so this is probably the problem as subtracting two `unsigned byte`s would lead to overflow and you would get that `253` instead of `-3`.

You need to convert those values into an `int`. Something like this could work:

```
...
avgA = int(img[(y-1),x]) + int(img[(y-1),(x+1)]) + int(img[(y-1),(x-1)])
avgC = int(img[(y+1),x]) + int(img[(y+1),(x+1)]) + int(img[(y+1),(x-1)])
avgT = int(img[(y-1),(x-1)]) + int(img[y,(x-1)]) + int(img[(y+1),(x-1)])
avgB = int(img[(y-1),(x+1)]) + int(img[y,(x+1)]) + int(img[(y+1),(x+1)])

imgC[y, x] = avgA - avgC
imgD[y, x] = avgT - avgB
...
```

But I'm pretty sure you would get better (faster, less error prone code) results using generic convolution
function, like `PIL.Image.filter(''<filter>'')` with filter matrix created using
`PIL.ImageFilter.Kernel(..)` for PIL library - http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageFilter.html
Or `convolve` of `numpy/scipy` libraries, as shown here: http://juanreyero.com/article/python/python-convolution.html

**Edit**: as Julien Spronck pointed out - your resulting value in `imgE` is completely out of range and you should generally divide it by a number of pixels (i.e. sum of all values in the convolution matrix) used in calculation of that result.