# Strange result when subtracting two tensors

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I try to subtract two tensors and then convert every negative value to zero using relu function, but i cannot do that because when i subtract two tensors, tensorflow for some reason add 256 to every negative value !!

```
img = mpimg.imread('/home/moumenshobaky/tensorflow_files/virtualenv/archive/training/Dessert/82 
 7.jpg')
img2 = tf.math.floordiv(img,64)*64
img3 = img2-img
# showing an example of the Flatten class and operation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
flatten = Flatten(dtype='float32')

print(flatten(img2))   
print(img3)
```

now the result is

```
tf.Tensor(
[[ 0  0  0 ... 64 64  0]
[ 0  0  0 ... 64  0  0]
[64 64  0 ... 64  0  0]
...
[64 64 64 ... 64 64 64]
[64 64 64 ... 64 64 64]
[64 64 64 ... 64 64 64]], shape=(384, 1536), dtype=uint8)
tf.Tensor(
[[198 197 213 ... 229 252 202]
[194 193 207 ... 235 193 207]
[250 253 198 ... 238 193 207]
...
[227 217 207 ... 218 230 242]
[226 216 206 ... 217 230 239]
[225 215 203 ... 214 227 235]], shape=(384, 1536), dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Are you subtracting a negative value, resulting in an addition?

Comment: no :/ actually the values are added to a constant value for some reason it's 256 i don't know why this happens

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could make it work using `tf.keras.utils.img_to_array` to convert the image into a numpy array to avoid any unknown behaviour.

I used [this image](https://storage.googleapis.com/kagglesdsdata/datasets/432700/821742/evaluation/Dessert/15.jpg?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=gcp-kaggle-com%40kaggle-161607.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20211009%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20211009T083105Z&X-Goog-Expires=259199&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=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) from i presume the same dataset.

```py
img = mpimg.imread('C:/Users/as/Downloads/15.jpg')
img2 = tf.math.floordiv(img,64)*64

# convert to arrays
img = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
img2 = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img2)

img3 = img2-img
# showing an example of the Flatten class and operation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
flatten = Flatten(dtype='float32')

print(flatten(img2))   
print(img3)
```

output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[192. 128.  64. ...   0.   0.   0.]
 [192. 128.  64. ...   0.   0.   0.]
 [192. 128. 128. ...   0.   0.   0.]
 ...
 [ 64.   0.   0. ...  64.   0.   0.]
 [ 64.   0.   0. ...  64.   0.   0.]
 [ 64.   0.   0. ...  64.   0.   0.]], shape=(512, 1536), dtype=float32)
[[[-17. -43. -58.]
  [-23. -51.  -3.]
  [-31. -61. -16.]
  ...
  [-20.  -7. -14.]
  [-20.  -7. -14.]
  [-20.  -7. -14.]]

 [[-19. -45. -60.]
  [-25. -53.  -5.]
  [-33. -63. -18.]
  ...
  [-20.  -7. -14.]
  [-20.  -7. -14.]
  [-21.  -8. -15.]]
 [[-21. -49.  -1.]
show more (open the raw output data in a text editor) ...
[-32. -31. -11.]
  ...
  [-30. -60. -15.]
  [-30. -60. -15.]
  [-30. -60. -15.]]]
```

---

The problem occured because the image `dtype` is `uint` which is unsigned, so it doesn't allow negative values (check a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261312/python-inputting-a-negative-value-into-array-keeps-giving-me-256-minus-that-val)).

so I found out you could also solve the problem with `tf.cast(img, dtype=tf.float32)`.

Comment: Great, thanks alot but do you have any idea why does this happen?

Comment: @moumenShobakey I updated the post to include what the problem was, and another simpler fix

Comment: Again, great, i had doubts that the issue was with the type but i didn't know that int8 is unsigned, thanks allot